# PrintRequestAttribute - PageRanges in AWT PrinterJob

Tags: java, printing, jakarta-ee, awt

With java.awt.print.PrinterJob, i added the PrintRequestAttribute - PageRanges, to print specific pages ranging between a lower bound and upper bound. It does not print from the specified lower bound but always starts printing from the first page. How to get it resolved?

Comment: If the question is still relevant can you post some sample code?